# Splitting pattern based on Regular Expressions

Tags: java, regex

I am trying to write a program to parse Java Garbage Collection logs. I just created a grammar that matches a minor collection. Once I have identified a pattern I would like to parse it into individual tokens. My question is, is there any elegant way to do this with my previously defined grammar?

```
public class RegexTestHarness {
  private final static String REGEX_SMALL_COLLECTION = "\\d+\\.\\d+: \\[GC \\d+.\\d+: \\[ParNew: \\d+K\\-\\>0K\\(\\d+K\\), \\d+.\\d+ secs\\] \\d+K\\-\\>\\d+K\\(\\d+K\\), \\d+.\\d+ secs\\]";

  public static void main(String[] args){
    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(REGEX_SMALL_COLLECTION);           
    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher("54.770: [GC 54.770: [ParNew: 5232768K->0K(5237824K), 1.1304192 secs] 5238622K->380448K(10480704K), 1.1306410 secs]");
    while (matcher.find()) {            
      System.out.println(matcher.group(0));
      System.out.println(matcher.start());
      System.out.println(matcher.end()); 
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: what's the question?  What you have seems like an excellent start, although I would write unit tests, each one with a line from a GC log

Comment: The string I pass to pattern.matcher is parsed correctly, meaning it matches the patter, but my next step is I would like to split the string into tokens. for the example above: 54.770, 54.770, 5232768,5237824,  1.1304192... and so on. I feel based upon my supplied pattern that there must be a some type of method I can call to split my pattern.

Comment: ah i got it now.  added an answer...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add groups to your regex.

`private final static String REGEX_SMALL_COLLECTION = "(\\d+\\.\\d+): \\[GC (\\d+.\\d+): \\[ParNew: \\d+K\\-\\>0K\\(\\d+K\\), \\d+.\\d+ secs\\] \\d+K\\-\\>\\d+K\\(\\d+K\\), \\d+.\\d+ secs\\]";`

and then access the groups to the values.  In the above example, I added parenthesis around the first two items you want -- this tells the regex engine to capture the matching substrings. You will need to add more.  As you are currently doing, you use [`Matcher.group()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html#group%28int%29) to get each group.  Note that group 0 is always the entire match. The rest are numbered from `1` up, in order of their opening parens `(`.